# Showing that a continuous map $f:X \to S^n$ which is not onto is always nullhomotopic

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification

This is a problem I came across recently.

Let $f:X \to S^n$ be a continuous map which is not onto. Then it is nullhomotopic.

My attempt:

Since $f:X \to S^n$ is not onto, there exist $s_0 \in S^n$ such that $f(x) \not = s_0$ for any $x \in X$. So we throw away $s_0$ and consider $S^n \setminus \{s_0\}$. So, we consider $f$ as a function from $X$ to $S^n \setminus \{s_0\}$. Now via the stereographic projection we may identify $S^n \setminus \{s_0\}$ with $\mathbb{R}^n$. Now $\mathbb{R}^n$ is contractible, so $id_{\mathbb{R}^n}:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is nullhomotopic, say $id_{\mathbb{R}^n} \simeq c_k$ ($c_k$ is a constant map). So $id_{\mathbb{R}^n} \circ f \simeq c_k \circ f$. Thus $f \simeq c_k \circ f$. Note $c_k \circ f$ is a constant map. So, $f$ is nullhomotopic.

PS: Let $H : X \times \mathbb{I} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a homotopy between $f$ and a constant map $c$. Since we identified $S^n \setminus \{s_0\}$ with $\mathbb{R}^n$, we have the inclusion $i:\mathbb{R}^n \hookrightarrow S^n$. So consider $G : X \times \mathbb{I} \to S^n$ defined by $G = i \circ H$. Its easy to see $G$ is homotopy between $f$ and $c$ when their codomains are considered to be $S^n$.

This is my argument. However I am not happy with identifying $S^n \setminus \{s_0\}$ with $\mathbb{R}^n$. But I can't find anything wrong with my argument. I would appreciate if someone could verify or give hints to improve the proof.

Comment: Why are you not happy with identifying $S^n\setminus\{s_0\}$ with $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @psl2Z idk, just a feeling. is my proof correct? should i make it more rigorous?

Comment: Well, the ideal is totally correct, but it is non written in a clean way.

Comment: @psl2Z how should i make it more neat?

Comment: I think it's fine if you delete everything after PS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is $f = i\circ F$ for some continuous maps $F: X \to \mathbb{R}^n$ and $i: \mathbb{R}^n \to S^n$. Since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is contractible, it holds $F \simeq c_{x_0}$ with $c_{x_0} : X \to \mathbb{R}^n, x \mapsto x_0$ constant. Therefore $f = i \circ F \simeq i \circ c_{x_0} = c_{i(x_0)}$.